# Force Google Photos to upload or sync photos when connected to WiFi even if the app is not open

Tags: sync, google-photos

Google Photos app has a cloud sync feature. However, based on observation, the photos are only synced when the user opens the app.

How to force Google Photos to upload photos when connected to WiFi even if the app is not open?